# Delete Scheduled Jobs using Apex in one go

Tags: apex, dml, dmlexception

I have More than 2500 Scheduled Jobs and i want to delete them but the issue is when i try system.abortJobId(jobId); on a list of job id which i fetched using soql it says not more than 150 DML operations allowed ...
How can i Delete all the Jobs in one go

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't in that no bulk API is provided.

You could use one of the asynchronous mechanisms e.g. [batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) to break the work up and so stay within that DML governor limit for each block of aborts.

Comment: yes thts something which i can  do thnksss